# Solve trigonometric equation $\sin(5a)+\sin(a)+\cos(2a)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find all general solutions to $$\sin(5a)+\sin(a)+\cos(2a)=0$$
How would I go about to solve this? I don't know what to do with the $sin(5a)$ term.

Comment: Convert the sum $\sin(5a)+\sin(a)$ into product: $\sin(5a)+\sin(a)=2\sin(3a)\cos(2a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin\left(5x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(2x\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\left(2\sin\left(3x\right)+1\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)\tag1$$

Comment: Don't answer question-only questions with no shown work, even with just a hint.